# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.weblogic.application.ModuleException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, weblogic12c

> Blockquote

i am getting below error not able to resolve it can anyone help me in this . **Using springboot version 1.4.3 , servlet 3.0  weblogic 12.2.1.4** 
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Class;)V"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:**

> Blockquote

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions of Spring (Boot) never do that.

Comment: using only <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>  springboot

Comment: The fact that you are using that version doesn't mean you aren't using other libraries that pull in other vesions. These issues only come from mixing incompatible versions. Without your pom/gradle build we cannot see which/what it is.